# Dynamically assign column of one python array to empty python array

Tags: python, numpy

```
import sys
import numpy as np
   
arrNew = [['t', 'a', 't', 'k', 'a', 'p', 'c'], ['s', 'p', 't', 'n', 'o', 'e', 'o'], ['u', 't', 'n', 'l', 'd', 't', 'i'], ['o', 'm', 'a', 'y', 'w', 'x', 'z']]

j = [([None] * 7) for i in range(4)]

arrNewlyGenerated = np.array(j)

arrNewlyGenerated[:, 0] = arrNew[:, 4]
arrNewlyGenerated[:, 1] = arrNew[:, 0]
arrNewlyGenerated[:, 2] = arrNew[:, 2]
arrNewlyGenerated[:, 3] = arrNew[:, 1]
arrNewlyGenerated[:, 4] = arrNew[:, 6]
arrNewlyGenerated[:, 5] = arrNew[:, 3]
arrNewlyGenerated[:, 6] = arrNew[:, 5]
```

Currently I've hard coded it, I want to make ***arrNewlyGenerated*** dynamic. Any Help?

Comment: Arrays in numpy *are* dynamic arrays - what do you mean when you say you want to make the array 'dynamic'? Are you looking to randomise the order of elements in the new array? Is there some other rule that determines the order in your example that you didn't explain?

Comment: Your code could be simplified by using `arrNewlyGenerated = arrNew[:, [4, 0, 2, 1, 6, 3, 5]].copy()` (if you convert `arrNew` to a numpy array first)

Comment: Hard to understand what you mean by "hardcoding" it. Hardcoding which logic?

Comment: `np.array(arrNew)` makes a (4,7) shape array.  But if you can use `arrNew[:, 4]` it already is one (as opposed to a list of lists)

Comment: If you just want to randomly permute the columns: `arrNewlyGenerated = np.array(arrNew)[:, np.random.permutation(7)]`

Comment: order = [2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 7, 5]
arrNew = 
[
['t', 'a',  't',    'k',  'a',  'p',  'c'], 
['s', 'p',  't',   'n',  'o',  'e',  'o'], 
['u', 't',   'n',  'l',   'd',  't',    'i'], 
['o', 'm', 'a',  'y',  'w',  'x',  'z']
]

Now what I want is the new dynamic array should follow the order of the above list as follows:

1st column ['a' 'o' 'd' 'w']
2nd column ['t' 't' 'n' 'a']
3rd column ['t' 't' 'n' 'a']
4th column ['a' 'p' 't' 'm']

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The first line makes a list:

```
In [78]: alist = [['t', 'a', 't', 'k', 'a', 'p', 'c'], ['s', 'p', 't', 'n', 'o', 'e', 'o'], ['u', 't', 'n', 'l', 'd', 't', 'i'], ['o', 'm', 'a', 'y', 'w', 'x', 'z']]

In [79]: alist
Out[79]: 
[['t', 'a', 't', 'k', 'a', 'p', 'c'],
 ['s', 'p', 't', 'n', 'o', 'e', 'o'],
 ['u', 't', 'n', 'l', 'd', 't', 'i'],
 ['o', 'm', 'a', 'y', 'w', 'x', 'z']]
```

That list cannot be index as `alist[:,0]`; but if it is an array:

```
In [80]: arr = np.array(alist)

In [81]: arr
Out[81]: 
array([['t', 'a', 't', 'k', 'a', 'p', 'c'],
       ['s', 'p', 't', 'n', 'o', 'e', 'o'],
       ['u', 't', 'n', 'l', 'd', 't', 'i'],
       ['o', 'm', 'a', 'y', 'w', 'x', 'z']], dtype='<U1')

In [82]: order = np.array([4,0,2,1,6,3,5])
```

Then it can be indexed with `arr[:,3]`, or with the `order` array:

```
In [83]: arr[:,order]
Out[83]: 
array([['a', 't', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'p'],
       ['o', 's', 't', 'p', 'o', 'n', 'e'],
       ['d', 'u', 'n', 't', 'i', 'l', 't'],
       ['w', 'o', 'a', 'm', 'z', 'y', 'x']], dtype='<U1')
```

Your 'newlyGenerated' makes an (4,7) object dtype array:

```
In [84]: x=np.array([([None] * 7) for i in range(4)])

In [85]: x.shape
Out[85]: (4, 7)

In [86]: x
Out[86]: 
array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

`np.empty` does that too:

```
In [87]: np.empty((4,7), dtype=object)
Out[87]: 
array([[None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None],
       [None, None, None, None, None, None, None]], dtype=object)
```

`arr`, made from the lists of strings is 'U1' dtype; it could be object dtype with `arr.astype(object)`.

Comment: First of all thankyou for your explanation. "Then it can be indexed with arr[:,3], or with the order array." Can you please explain the assignment part ? the for loops you will be using for the order to be correct?